# Where is Color Animation in JQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted to make a color changing background as in [here](http://orteil.dashnet.org/index.php), so I looked it up and found [this place](http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/its-a-rainbow-color-changing-text-and-backgrounds/). There's a link to the color animation jQuery plugin but *apparently* the [link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) **doesn't work**. I have tried downloading the [jQuery-ui.zip](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.12.0-beta.1) and in the check boxes, there was nothing about color animation. In the zip, I opened the index.html that showcased all the features, and found, you guessed it, nothing about color animation. There was some color animation, but it was all instantaneous. If you could provide me with a link or even a push in the right direction that would be great.

I know this doesn't belong in stackoverflow, but I couldn't find a better one.

Comment: None of the sites you refer to use the JQuery-UI frameworks. They generate the hue and then change the background. No plug-ins or UI elements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is already answered by the links user provides and has no relationship to JQuery-UI.

Comment: @Twisty but how exactly _do_ they change it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how they do it in the comments, just look at the Page Source. I found this:

```
<table class="main"><tr><td id="bg">
<table class="main"><tr><td style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
<div class="bordercolor" id="bordercolor">
<div id="text" class="text">
</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;opacity:0.5;padding:4px;font-size:8pt;text-align:left;">(c) Orteil 2011<br>proudly hosted by <a href="http://dashnet.org">dashnet.org</a></div>
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>

<script>
Nodes["main"].show();

function hsvToRgb(h, s, v){
    var r, g, b;

    var i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    var f = h * 6 - i;
    var p = v * (1 - s);
    var q = v * (1 - f * s);
    var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);

    switch(i % 6){
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}


var t=0;
function Rainbow()
{
var Col=hsvToRgb((t%100)/100,1,1);
document.getElementById("bordercolor").style.backgroundColor="rgb("+Math.floor(Col[0])+","+Math.floor(Col[1])+","+Math.floor(Col[2])+")";
//document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="rgb("+Math.floor(Col[0])+","+Math.floor(Col[1])+","+Math.floor(Col[2])+")";
t++;
setTimeout("Rainbow();",1000/10);
}

Rainbow();

</script>
```

A brief explanation and my own example making use of JQuery. No JQuery UI needed. See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9nkc7sd6/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bordercolor" id="bordercolor">
    <div id="text" class="text">
      I am a pretty pretty rainbow!
      <p><span id="hsv"></span>, <span id="rgb"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#bordercolor {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
    var r, g, b;

    var i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    var f = h * 6 - i;
    var p = v * (1 - s);
    var q = v * (1 - f * s);
    var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);

    switch (i % 6) {
      case 0:
        r = v, g = t, b = p;
        break;
      case 1:
        r = q, g = v, b = p;
        break;
      case 2:
        r = p, g = v, b = t;
        break;
      case 3:
        r = p, g = q, b = v;
        break;
      case 4:
        r = t, g = p, b = v;
        break;
      case 5:
        r = v, g = p, b = q;
        break;
    }

    return "rgb(" + Math.floor(r * 255) + "," + Math.floor(g * 255) + "," + Math.floor(b * 255) + ")";
  }
  var t = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    var col = hsvToRgb((t % 100) / 100, 1, 1);
    $("#bordercolor").css("background-color", col);
    $("#hsv").html("hsv(" + ((t % 100) / 100) + ",1,1)");
    $("#rgb").html(col);
    t++;
  }, 1000 / 10);
});
```

The important function here is the Hue Saturation Value (HSV) to Red Green Blue (RGB) `hsvToRgb()` function. This created the color codes we need and you can learn more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB

For this, we're really only looping over the Hue and incrementing it by 1/100th (1%) every 100 ms or 1/10th of a second. This cycles through all 100 hues in 10 seconds.

As we loop, we adjust the CSS `background-css` of our element `div` using it's ID selector.